# Передать в переменную js значения поля

Tags: jquery, javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/t6yanva0/

Как можно вывести введенные в форме значения в див (#form-value), при клике на инпут (input.feedback)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так: https://jsfiddle.net/t6yanva0/1/ ?

Comment: оно самое. спасибо.